# Apache VirtualHost, multiple sites. 1 ssl with redirect and 1 regular http

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, apache-2.2

I've got a server with one site which I am redirecting to https via

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/secure
     ServerName secure.com
     Redirect / https://secure.com
</VirtualHost>
```

That works no problem.

Now I'm trying to add another non-secure site

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/notsecure
    ServerName notsecure.com
</VirtualHost>
```

of course, because the redirect is on '/', all sites are getting redicted.
I've tried changing the Redirect to the full document root, but no luck.

Comment: Does your configuration have a `NameVirtualHost *:80` directive somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it does have NameVirtualHost *:80. should it not?

Comment: No, that's fine. The `NameVirtualHost` directive needs to be there in order to use name-based virtual hosting.

Answer (score 2):

If you have NameVirtualHost on, you have to use the IP. NameVirtualHost is needed if you are running SSL, or running VirtualHosts on different IP addresses.

```
<VirtualHost 172.16.4.1:80>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/secure
     ServerName secure.com
     Redirect / https://secure.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 17.16.4.1:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/notsecure
    ServerName notsecure.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to declare this (best in httpd.conf/apache2.conf), this is important! DO NO USE ASTERISK "*"

```
NameVirtualHost IP_or_hostname:80
NameVirtualHost IP_or_hostname:443
```

And in your virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost IP_or_hostname:443>
        ServerName whateveryouwant
        DocumentRoot /www/blahblah/

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/blahblah.key
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/blahblah.crt
        SSLProtocol all
        SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost IP_or_hostname:80>
        ServerName whateveryouwant
        DocumentRoot /www/blahblah

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        LogLevel warn
        ServerSignature Off

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blahblahblah$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://blahblahblah/$1 [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mod_rewrite:

Your conf should look like this:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80> 
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/secure
 ServerName secure.com

 RewriteEngine On  
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
 RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `Redirect` is fine. mod_rewrite is not the hammer matching the nail this time.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

# default virtual host
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName _default_
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/default
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName secure.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/secure
    RedirectPermanent / https://secure.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName secure.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/secure
    SSLEngine on
    # other SSL related directives
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName notsecure.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/notsecure
</VirtualHost>
```

You should also take a look at the [VirtualHost Examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) in the Apache httpd documentation.